# Node.js https server doesn't work when I separate it in two files

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl

I have this node.js https server that works when it is in one **app.js** file but when I split it in 2 files it doesn't work anymore. I don't know why..

This **app.js** works

```
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const server = https.createServer({
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/privkey.pem'),
}, app)

server.listen(443)
```

But when I separate it in 2 files **app.js** and **certificate.js** it doesn't work anymore

**app.js**

```
const https = require('https')
const express = require('express')
const certificate = require('./certificate.js')

const app = express()

const server = https.createServer({
    certificate.cert,
    certificate.key,
}, app)

server.listen(443)
```

**certificate.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')

var certificate = {
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/cert.pem'),
    key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/www.4evergaming.com/privkey.pem'),
}

exports.certificate = certificate
```

I'm getting this syntax error

```
certificate.cert
           ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
```

I also tried to to this

```
const server = https.createServer(certificate, app)
```

And I was getting this error

> connection failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH

*So when it was all in **app.js** file it worked perfectly. But when I tried to separate it in 2 files it doesn't work anymore..*

Comment: Jeremy answer is correct, but also for the future, you could try to log the `certificate` variable to see if it's correctly imported, then you would know it would be a syntax error or an import error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a JS syntax error, it has nothing to do with your app being split in two files.

This object is invalid :

```
{
    certificate.cert, // SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
    certificate.key,  //SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.'
}
```

Try this :

```
https.createServer({
    cert : certificate.cert,
    key : certificate.key,
})
```

**EDIT :** including @StephaneVanraes comments :

You are also importing the certificate wrong, try `const { certificate } = require('./certificate.js')`

Also, since the property names are the same in both cases you could use the spread operator here: `https.createServer({ ...certificate })`

Comment: Getting this error now ````Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH````

Comment: what if you `console.log(certificate)` ? Is it what you expect?

Comment: You are also importing the certificate wrong, try `const { certificate } = require('./certificate.js')`

Comment: Note that since the property names are the same in both case you could use the spread operator here: `https.createServer({ ...certificate })`

Comment: @JeremyThille could you update your answer to include Stephane's comment? So that if anyone else has the same problem they will see it.